# how to create an unknown number of TKinter objects in a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a scrolling frame in TKinter. and a list of tuples I have taken from my database(managed by SQlite) for each tuple in the list i want to create a row of widgets in the scrolling frame, using a for loop. the row includes the row number ,a checkbox, the title taken from the tuple and a button that opens a link taken from the tuple. the issue I have is that I don't know how to create an unknown number of rows of widgets in TKinter and also be able to reference them. the code below works in that it creates the rows etc but once they are created I cannot reference individual widgets. this is important because the checkbox on click needs to update an IsActive column in my database.(help with that would also be welcome). I have tried using a dictionary to hold StringVar()s for the checkbox's but Im pretty sure I have done this wrong.

the class itself is a frame in a TKinter window. I appreciate this might be a silly question I am a beginner

```
class details(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="details", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.95, anchor = tk.CENTER)

        myframe= tk.Frame(self,relief=tk.GROOVE,bd=1)
        myframe.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor = tk.CENTER, width = 750, height = 450)

        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(myframe)
        self.frame=tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        myscrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

        myscrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both")
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.frame,anchor='nw')
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>",self.myfunction)
        self.data()

    def data(self):
        lock.acquire(True)
        c.execute("select * from story")
        lock.release()
        results = c.fetchall()
        print(results)
        i = 0
        checkbuttons = {}
## the for loop where rows are created.
        for item in results:

            checkbuttons[item[0]] = tk.IntVar()
            b = item[4]
            s = tk.StringVar()
            tk.Label(self.frame,text=i).grid(row=i,column=0)
            tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text="", variable=checkbuttons[item[0]], onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(row=i,column=1)

            tk.Label(self.frame,textvariable=s, width = 90).grid(row=i,column=2, sticky=tk.W)
            tk.Button(self.frame,text="LINK", command=lambda a = b: self.open_link(a)).grid(row=i,column=3)
            s.set(str(item[3]))
            i+=1
    def myfunction(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"),width=750,height=500)

    def open_link(self, link):
        print(link)
        webbrowser.open(link, new=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> the issue I have is that I don't know how to create an unknown number of rows of widgets in TKinter and also be able to reference them.

The simplest solution is to put them in a list or dictionary, or in your case, a list of dictionaries where each row in the list is a dictionary with the data you want to remember.

So, start with the data you want to remember. In your case I'm guessing we want to be able to get the href, and we want to be able get or set the associated variable.

In the following example I've tried to use more sensible variable names than `b`, `i`, etc. and organized the code by logical functions: pulling data from an item, creating the widgets, laying out the widgets, and then saving the data.

```
for rownum, item in enumerate(results):
    title = item[3]
    href = item[4]

    var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    row_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=rownum)
    title_label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=title)
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, text="", variable=var,
                        onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    button = tk.Button(self.frame, text="LINK",
                       command=lambda rownum=rownum: self.open_link(rownum))

    row_label.grid(row=rownum, column=0)
    cb.grid(row=rownum, column=1)
    title_label.grid(row=rownum, column=2, sticky="w")
    button.grid(row=rownum, column=3)

    # store the data in a dictionary so we can reference it later
    row = {
        "href": href,
        "var": var
    }
    self.rows.append(row)
```

For illustrative purposes, I've modified `open_link` to accept the row number rather than the link. We can use the row number to access the href, and I also have it automatically select the associated checkbutton just to prove that you can.

```
def open_link(self, rownum):
    link = self.rows[rownum]['href']
    self.rows[rownum]['var'].set(1)
    print(link)
```